# System.getProperty("line.separator") equivalent in GWT or adding new-line to String in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I just wanted to add a new line to string, I'm using GWT for client side components.
When I'm trying to compile my project,I'm getting compile time error. I heard that there is no
direct support for `System.getProperty("line.separator")` .

error desc:

> [ERROR] Line 152: The method getProperty(String, String) in the type System is not applicable for the arguments (String)

If the compiler requires two arguments, what is the second arg I need to use. I'm not strictly bounded to use  line.separator, if there are any other alternatives to add new line to String.

Comment: Try using `java.lang.System.getProperty("line.separator");`. If this solves the error, it means there's a `System` class in one of your packages.

Comment: `System.lineSeparator()` is a shortcut for `System.getProperty("line.separator")` as of newer versions of Java.

Comment: What is the output of `System.class.getName()`?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, I did according to your advice but still geting the same gwt-compile issue

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi, I'm using eclipse with jdk1.6 and gwt2.5.1 plugin, my question:: is System.lineSeparator() does not cause the gwt-compile problem

Comment: Maybe the compiler is looking for [`System.getProperty(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) but is odd. Anyway, try to call this method, the second argument is for default value in case the property is not set.

Comment: @ArunRvrjc You haven't told me the output of that yet...

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza, I even tried like this.. System.getProperty("line.separator","");.. but still getting the same

Comment: @ damryfbfnetsi, System.class.getName() gives complete qualifier name of that class(java.lang.System)

Comment: Closed this question as duplicate. Check the other Q/A where this is already covered.

Comment: If you are in the client you can simply use the constant "<br />" as the line separator. AFAIK this is the only line separator for html \r\n and \r and \n will simply print the ascii.